# Change proxy if Error or Change proxy if one is already used

Tags: c#

So I am not sure how to make system like for each web request choose other proxy & if comes error then choose other proxy as well. I don't have made up any code for it, but I hope there's someone who can do it for me.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Do you want to check `IP` and `Port` if they are not blocked?

Comment: No, I want. Example proxy is: 8.8.8.8:8888 and it's sent to one Website from list then if the first one from list is sent then it takes other one from lists and sends that. IF proxy gives error then it switches proxy

Comment: http://prntscr.com/88ngce

Comment: If the proxy list is 900 Lines and the Index is [0] then it only takes first one, but yeah. How can I make that system if one proxy is sent or error comes then it takes other one.

Comment: `but I hope there's someone who can do it for me` . Really? No.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

Need a simple class

```
public class IpAndPort
{
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
}
```

Now put proxies into list as:

```
var proxies = new List<IpAndPort>
{
     new IpAndPort{ IpAddress = "192.168.1.1", Port = "8012" },
     new IpAndPort{ IpAddress = "192.118.1.2", Port = "8072" },
     new IpAndPort{ IpAddress = "222.167.1.7", Port = "9012" },
     new IpAndPort{ IpAddress = "172.145.1.4", Port = "82" }
     //...
}
```

Now call the following method for web request

```
var concurrentBag = new ConcurrentBag<IpAndPort>(proxies);
GetProxyWebResponse(txtUrl.Text.Trim(), concurrentBag);


private async Task<string> GetProxyWebResponse(string url, ConcurrentBag<IpAndPort> concurrentBag)
{   
      while (!concurrentBag.IsEmpty)
      {
           IpAndPort proxy;
           if (!concurrentBag.TryTake(out proxy)) continue;
           try
           {
                while (true)
                {   
                     if (!SocketConnect(proxy.IpAddress, Convert.ToInt32(proxy.Port)))
                     {
                          break;
                     }
                     var webProxy = new WebProxy(proxy.IpAddress, proxy.Port)
                     {
                          BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                          Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
                     };
                     var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                     request.Proxy = webProxy;          
                     request.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
                     try
                     {
                          var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                          string error;
                          var responseFromServer = GetResponseText(response, out error);
                          //do work with responseFromServer 
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                          //ExceptionLogger.CreateFile(ex);
                     }
                     await Task.Delay(2000);
               }                        
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
         await Task.Delay(6000);
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Helping Methods

```
public static bool SocketConnect(string host, int port)
{
    var is_success = false;
    try
    {
         var connsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
         connsock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 200);
         Thread.Sleep(500);
         var hip = IPAddress.Parse(host);
         var ipep = new IPEndPoint(hip, port);
         connsock.Connect(ipep);
         if (connsock.Connected)
         {
             is_success = true;
         }
         connsock.Close();
     }
     catch (SocketException)
     {
         is_success = false;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         is_success = false;
     }
     return is_success;
}
private static string GetResponseText(HttpWebResponse response, out string error)
{
     error = string.Empty;
     if (response == null)
     {
         error = "Listed proxy servers did not responding.";
         return null;
     }
     var responseFromServer = string.Empty;
     var responceStream = response.GetResponseStream();
     if (responceStream != null)
     {
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(responceStream))
         {
             responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
     }
     return responseFromServer;
}
```